# Palworld pets go to sleep then never bother waking up again

Tags: palworld

So as the title says, my pals will go to sleep and then just not wake up the next day or after a "rest period". Its happening in all of my bases. If i pull them out and put them back in the box they work for that day, then repeat the Snow white act. [image]

[image]